# How to access array in jQuery live event?

Tags: jquery, arrays, live

I have the following code:

```
var numberOfSelectedOptions = new Array();
numberOfSelectedOptions[0]=0;
numberOfSelectedOptions[1]=0;
numberOfSelectedOptions[2]=0;

$("a.tagvariantoption").live("click", function(){
 alert(numberOfSelectedOptions[2]);
});
```

The alert always says "undefined". It works perfectly when alerting outside of the live event though. Any ideas on why my array is undefined or unknown within the live event?

Heres some extra info:

```
var startcount = 0; 
var numberOfSelectedOptions = new Array(); 
numberOfSelectedOptions[0]=0; 
numberOfSelectedOptions[1]=0; 
numberOfSelectedOptions[2]=0; 

$("a.tagvariantoption").live("click", function(){ 
  alert(startcount); //gives 0 
  alert(numberOfSelectedOptions[0]); //gives undefined??? 
)};
```

The HTML is working because startcount is printed correctly, but my array stays unknown within the event.

Comment: can you add your html to the question

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer - this works fine for me in Firefox 3.5.5 and IE 6.0.

Comment: html is working fine, the click is detected and alerts are being printed. Array is unknown within the event, while a normal variable is perfectly accessible

Comment: Works perfectly check demo site http://jsbin.com/avuxa

Comment: Is numberOfSelectedOptions declared or manipulated elsewhere in your page?

Comment: Just a quick comment - `var numberOfSelectedOptions=[0,0,0];` is a much more compact method of setting up that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it somehow like this:

var selectedOptionsCounter = new Array(0,0,0);

from then on, that array is accessible in the live event, no idea what was wrong before though.

Comment: What browser were you using to test?

Comment: Um suddenly you array has a different name numberOfSelectedOptions vs selectedOptionsCounter?